# Get multiple child records as a list in each row MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

[image: DB Schema]

I have users table each user has multiple roles.
I want to show a list of users and in list all roles of each user.
Like ***user1*** has admin, and supervisor role then show 1 row for user 1 and in roles field show
***admin, supervisor***
[image: Frontend View]

I am working on laravel. Tried through model relationship

```
public function roles(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\UserRole');
}
```

Fetching...

```
    $users = User::all();
    $roles = $users->roles;
    return $users;
```

Also tried

```
$users->roles();
Users::roles();
```

none is working...   It says roles is not defined...

Comment: Do you have `Role` or `UserRole` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching...

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
return $users;
```

Show users in table.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($user->roles as $role)
                {{ $role->name }}
                {{ $loop->iteration == $loop->count ? ', ':'' }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>Your actions</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```